# How to upload file to Nexus using RestSharp?

Tags: nexus, restsharp

This is the document on how to upload to Nexus using REST API and cURL:https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-

Below is my C# code, it returns a Completed status, but the file is not uploaded. Don't know what's missing.

```
 public void uploadArtifact()
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("artifact/maven/content/", Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("r", "releases");
        request.AddParameter("hasPom", "false");
        request.AddParameter("p", "zip");
        request.AddParameter("e", "zip");
        request.AddParameter("g", "otpp.devops");        
        request.AddParameter("a", "githubSuspsendInactiveADAccounts");
        request.AddParameter("v", "1.0.1");
        request.AddFile("githubSuspsendInactiveADAccounts-1.0.1.zip", @"C:\\Temp\\Nexus\\githubSuspsendInactiveADAccounts-1.0.1.zip"); //Completed but not uploaded

        IRestResponse response = this.restSharpAPI.Execute(this.client, request);
        Console.WriteLine("Response received: {0}", response.ResponseStatus);        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this work, haven't figured out how to add the path:

```
request.AddFile("githubSuspsendInactiveADAccounts-1.0.1.zip", "githubSuspsendInactiveADAccounts-1.0.1.zip");
```